# How to prove P ⊆ Co-NP

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np, p-vs-np

My approach

> Let L ∈ P
>
> $\exists$ Turing Machine $M_1$ which decides L.
>
> We can easily construct $M_2$ which decides $\bar{L}$
>
> $\bar{L}$ ∈ CO-NP $\implies$ P ⊆ Co-NP

I'm not sure whether its a correct way to prove this or not. I found this method here [Link](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~hsinmu/courses/_media/ada_11fall/hw6-sol.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because P = Co-P: if we can find a solution for a problem in Polynomial time, we can also decide in Polynomial time that it does NOT have a solution. Now, since P ⊆ NP we have that the complement of this problem is in Co-NP. But the complement of any problem in P is in Co-P and therefore any complement of any P problem is in Co-NP. And since the complement of any P problem is Co-P = P, we have P ⊆ Co-NP

Comment: I don't understand this line " since P ⊆ NP we have that the complement of this problem is in Co-NP". Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: Are you trying to say that - as P ⊆ NP then CO-P ⊆ CO-NP but since P = CO-P this implies P ⊆ CO-NP.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

A deterministic polynomial time machine for a language $L$ can easily be converted to a non-deterministic polynomial time machine which has the same operational semantics (that is, it operates deterministically), and so it both non-deterministically and co-non-deterministically accept $L$ – just check the definitions.